# Routing of 2 Gateways via a Layer 2 Switch

Tags: routing, switch, ospf, layer2, layer3

Please refer to the network diagram below, it is a very simplified version of an actual network installation.

The Router has 3 Vlans, OSPF has been configured and all the 3 vlans have been added to Area 0 so they can communicate with each other.
The Switch is a PnP Layer 2 managed switch.

With the current setup, we are facing an issue: End Device 1 cannot communicate with End Device 2.
However, if we break the link between the Switch and Vlan2, the 2 End Devices are able to communicate with each other.

Can somebody please explain why this phenomenon is occuring, and how it can be solved while maintaining both the connections from the switch to the router.

[image]

The Router is an Extreme Summit X450a device. Refer to the sample config below:

```
create vlan “VLAN1”
configure vlan VLAN1 tag 10
configure vlan VLAN1 add ports 1-4 untagged
configure vlan VLAN1 ipaddress 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.0

create vlan “VLAN2”
configure vlan VLAN2 tag 20
configure vlan VLAN2 add ports 5-8 untagged
configure vlan VLAN2 ipaddress 10.0.1.1 255.255.255.0

create vlan “VLAN3”
configure vlan VLAN3 tag 30
configure vlan VLAN3 add ports 9-12 untagged
configure vlan VLAN3 ipaddress 10.0.2.1 255.255.255.0

enable ipforwarding vlan VLAN1
enable ipforwarding vlan VLAN2
enable ipforwarding vlan VLAN3

enable ipmcforwarding vlan VLAN1
enable ipmcforwarding vlan VLAN2
enable ipmcforwarding vlan VLAN3

configure ospf routerid 10.0.2.1
enable ospf
configure ospf add vlan VLAN1 area 0.0.0.0
configure ospf add vlan VLAN2 area 0.0.0.0
configure ospf add vlan VLAN3 area 0.0.0.0

configure pim add vlan VLAN1 dense
configure pim add vlan VLAN2 dense
configure pim add vlan VLAN3 dense
enable pim
```

Comment: Need configurations of the router and the switch

Comment: HI fredpbaker, for the switch, we have used it as a PnP, with no configuration done. You may refer to the router config in this file https://db.tt/0jjqySqD

Comment: Which ports are going to the L2 switch from the Extreme switch?

Comment: For VLAN1, i have used port 1, VLAN2 uses port 5, and VLAN3 uses port 9. So ports 5 and 9 go to the L2 switch...

Comment: The L2 switch has an address, so I'll assume it has a CLI... look at it's mac-address-table to see where it thinks things are. It looks like ED2's traffic is arriving at the router on the wrong port.

Comment: Well, the precise reason for 2 links is because our NMS needs to know the status of all network equipment as well as end devices. I will check the mac-address table of the L2 switch. but if the problem is as @Ricky Beam has described, how would we go about solving it? Ofcourse, this is assuming that the IP Addresses of the equipment cannot be changed...

Comment: Extreme supports per vlan STP, but YLearn's explanation is plausible assuming you are not running pvst or mst.  If STP is indeed the problem, you would see the vlan 3 port to the other switch blocked in STP.  Assuming this is the problem, dot1q with LACP removes STP blocking issues, and provides redundancy for vlan 2 & 3 links.

Comment: To clarify, Extreme does support PVST+, but this requires a spanning tree domain to be configured for each VLAN. Also, MST operates with a single topology for devices that are not configured for the same MST region.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

The Extreme Summit X450a is actually a L3 switch, not a router, so your problem is most likley that spanning tree is putting the second (VLAN3) inter-switch link in blocking mode.  When you disconnect the first (VLAN2) inter-switch link, STP transitions the second link to forwarding mode making the second station reachable.

Instead of two links carrying one VLAN each, you should be using a single tagged or trunk port between the two switches.

Comment: But there should be no bridging loop if he is using one VLAN per port to the switch. Looks strange to me.

Comment: I can confirm that stp is disabled on the L3 Switch, as the default configuration is STP Disabled. so i dont think STP is the case here. Yup, something is very strange.

Comment: @DanielDib, stp is layer-2. from that perspective, a bpdu left on one port and came back in on another.

Comment: @user79134, the strangeness is the result of a switch being plugged into a switch. I'm guessing the x450a isn't using individual MACs for each VLAN which will confuse the L2 switch. Or the L3 switch is answering ARP on the wrong interface(s). [from each end, ping each interface]

Comment: @DanielDib, unless you are using a proprietary extension to spanning-tree, there is no VLAN distinction.  As opposed to something like Cisco's per VLAN spanning-tree (PVST+) - CST, RSTP, and MST (between switches of different regions) all only have one spanning-tree topology and this is a very common configuration mistake.

Comment: @YLearn True. I'm so used to Cisco's STP that I'm thinking that's the default while most actually run CST.

Comment: @user79134, even if spanning tree is disabled by default on the L3 switch (which is an odd default for an enterprise L3 switch, but I am not overly familiar with Extreme), you don't mention if spanning tree is running on the L2 switch.  Depending on the "root" determined for the STP topology, the blocked port can be either of the two switches.